# Converting base 20 to int

Tags: c, radix

I am trying to convert base 20 to `int`. For example if I have `"1A"` it needs to be converted to `30`, and so on. I have developed the code but it is giving issues in running. Code is as below in **C** programming language:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    char converted[20] = "1A";
    itov(converted);

    return 0;
}

void itov(char vigesimalStr[])
{
    int length = 0;
    for (int i = 0; vigesimalStr[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        length++;
    }

    int base = 20;
    int result = 0;
    int power = 1;
    int num = 0;
    for (int j = length; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        if (val(vigesimalStr[j]) >= base)
        {
            printf("Invalid Number");
            return -1;
        }

        num += val(vigesimalStr[j]) * power;
        power = power * base;

    }

}

int val(char c)
{
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
        return (int)c - '0';
    else
        return (int)c - 'A' + 10;
}
```

Comment: Is this an exercise or homework assignment that prohibits use of `strtol`-family functions? If not, I'd use one of those.

Comment: "issues in running" is not a valid problem description. Also please indent your code properly.

Comment: FWIW `val` and `itov` have no prototypes before used.

Comment: i have added the val function underneath. you may see it. i can use strtol function but how to get int(c) value like in other languages.

Comment: `power = power * base;` can `int` overflow (undefined behavior), even if `num += val(vigesimalStr[j]) * power;` does not.

Comment: There are a number of corner cases: `"1@"` (invalid digit), `""` (empty), `"12345678"`.(`power * base` OF), `"-123"` (negatives) `"  123"` (leading WS).  Perhaps these are beyond your current goals?

Answer (score 1):

I will begin by stating the obvious, there is already a library function that can convert a string containing a number in any base from (I believe) 2 to 36:

```
printf("%ld\n", strtol("1A", NULL, 20));
// Output: 30
```

If, however, as part of an exercise or homework assignment the use of this and similar library functions are prohibited, I will not do your homework for you, but I will instead give you a description of the high level algorithm for reading an integer in an arbitrary base, N:

1. Initialize an `accumulator` variable at zero.
2. Initialize a count variable `i` at `0`.
3. Multiply `accumulator` by N.
4. Get the numeric value of the base-N digit currently in `str[i]`, and add that to `accumulator` (your `val` function).
5. Increment `i`.
6. If `str[i]` is `'\0'`, return `accumulator` and exit. Otherwise, go to step 3.

Answer (score 0):

Two key issues I see in your code:

```
void itov(char vigesimalStr[])
// ...
    return -1;
```

The `itov()` function can't be `void` if it returns -1 on error.  It also fails to return the correct value on success!

```
for (int j = length; j >= 0; j--)
```

When running a sequence backward, you want to start at `length - 1` as `length` itself is never a valid index as it's the last index plus one.

Below is a rework of your code with the above issues fixed and other lesser issues tidied up:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BASE 20

int val(char c)
{
    if ('0' <= c && c <= '9')
        return c - '0';

    return c - 'A' + 10;
}

int itov(char vigesimalStr[])
{
    int length = 0;

    for (length = 0; vigesimalStr[length] != '\0'; length++)
    {
        // nothing to see here
    }

    int power = 1;
    int number = 0;

    for (int j = length - 1; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        int digit = val(vigesimalStr[j]);

        if (digit >= BASE)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Invalid Number\n");
            return -1;
        }

        number += digit * power;
        power *= BASE;
    }

    return number;
}

int main()
{
    char to_convert[20] = "1A";

    printf("%d\n", itov(to_convert));

    return 0;
}
```